# Categorize ordering column in according two columns in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to enumerate the Customer-Assessor group in ascending order. Restarting every Client. Could you help me how to do it? I've tried using the groupby function, however, I'm not getting it to be restarted for each client.

Here is an example of the dataframe:

| Date | Customer | Advisor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | A | AA |
| 02/01/2023 | A | BB |
| 03/01/2023 | A | CC |
| 04/01/2023 | A | AA |
| 01/01/2023 | B | AA |
| 02/01/2023 | B | BB |
| 03/01/2023 | B | AA |
| 04/01/2023 | B | CC |

Follow the expected result:
The date is important, but the dataframe is already sorted by date.

| Date | Customer | Advisor | Customer-Advisor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | A | AA | 1 |
| 02/01/2023 | A | BB | 2 |
| 03/01/2023 | A | CC | 3 |
| 04/01/2023 | A | AA | 1 |
| 01/01/2023 | B | AA | 1 |
| 02/01/2023 | B | BB | 2 |
| 03/01/2023 | B | AA | 1 |
| 04/01/2023 | B | CC | 3 |

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With [`pd.Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html#pandas.Series.factorize) to encode `Advisor` values as categorical variables:

```
df['Customer-Advisor'] = np.ravel([g['Advisor'].factorize()[0] + 1 
                                   for _, g in df.groupby('Customer', sort=False)])
```

---

```
          Date Customer Advisor  Customer-Advisor
0  01/01/2023        A       AA                 1
1  02/01/2023        A       BB                 2
2  03/01/2023        A       CC                 3
3  04/01/2023        A       AA                 1
4  01/01/2023        B       AA                 1
5  02/01/2023        B       BB                 2
6  03/01/2023        B       AA                 1
7  04/01/2023        B       CC                 3
```

Comment: You are right, it is correct.

Comment: Or `df["Customer-Advisor"] = df.groupby(["Customer"])['Advisor'].transform(lambda g: g.factorize()[0]) + 1`

Comment: @jezrael answer it's working, but RomanPerekhrest answer didn't works. How do I choose jezrael answer as a valid solution? Thank you guys!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest for your answer I got ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @haraujo, It should work. Make sure you're not somehow changing the input df in the middle or mixing up different dataframes

Comment: @jezrael, I saw your alternative with `transform`, but it runs slower

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a unique ID for each Advisor.

```py
df["group_id"] = df.groupby(["Advisor"]).ngroup()
```

This starts the IDs at 0, but you can just add one to the column if you really care about that.

If you wanted to generate a unique ID for multiple groups (e.g. Customer AND Advisor), simply add to the list in groupby.

```py
df["group_id"] = df.groupby(["Customer", "Advisor"]).ngroup()
```